# ASP.Net architecture for passing upload to third party

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, youtube, architecture

I'm working on an application which is designed to stand on top of the YouTube API and pass uploads from the user to the YouTube.Videos.Insert endpoint (using the .NET client library they provide). Right now, my application is built as a simple ASP.NET MVC application, but I'm quickly realizing that may not be the best approach, because the issue quickly crops up that the upload process could be a rather long-running one.

What would the best-practice architecture be in order to do this effectively? My ideas thus far are:

- Some sort of queue strategy, where the MVC app puts the upload on the queue, and a background process pops it off and performs the further upload to YouTube. This seems inefficient, though, since it adds storing the file temporarily and retrieving it again for processing to the overall overhead of the application.
- A separate microservice API with an endpoint for receiving the actual upload, which I would contact via Javascript from the front-end of my app; it would receive the file, return a 202 Accepted, and pass the upload stream off into an async thread and process it immediately. This seems more efficient but I'm worried about scalability if anyone besides me ends up using this thing.

I would love additional architecture insight on the best way to approach this.

Comment: So if I understand right, your users will first upload to your application, and then your application uploads to the Youtube api?

Comment: Yes -- the idea is to provide an interface for them to save info that they're regularly including on multiple videos, so they don't have to type it every time they upload.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would approach this with a separate service API. The task of uploading many potentially large files is a long-running process that you don't want touching your web app. The main advantage to this approach is that if something goes wrong, it does not affect your web application. If an upload fails, you don't want to restart your web application to account for that.

Since you are worried about scalability regarding this approach, I would consider using a background task manager, which is perfect for these sort of fire-and-forget tasks. Personally, I use and recommend [Hangfire](https://www.hangfire.io/), as it comes with a beautiful [integrated dashboard](https://www.hangfire.io/img/ui/dashboard-sm.png) that lets you observe your tasks as they run. It also allows you to automatically retry on failure (configurable), and I think overall it suits your needs well.

I use it for a similar situation wherein I need to establish multiple websocket connections, and re-establish one if it were to fail. I have a small program that adds services to my Hangfire queue via arguments.

Other options include Quartz.Net and FluentScheduler, but unfortunately I am not nearly as familiar with them.

Comment: Ooh, interesting. I'll definitely have to check out Hangfire; that looks super useful. Thank you so much for the insight!